# how to update array obj in localStorage if item is already exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wondering how to update array obj in `localStorage` when an item is already exist, my `localStorage` create a new array after refresh rather than updating or adding new obj.

localStorage obj --

```
cart - [{"Product":"Coke","Price":"1.99","Quantity":"1x "}]
```

addToCart function where I add I push the object to `array[]`

```
var itemStorage = [];
for (var key in drinkCounter) {
...

        var cartObj = { Product: key, Price: drinkCounter[key].price, Quantity: drinkCounter[key].count + 'x ' }
        itemStorage.push(cartObj);
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(itemStorage));
...

    }
```

Here's a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svL8omhw/1/), so once you added an item and refresh the page and add the same or new item it recreates the `localStorage`, how can I update it instead of recreating a new one everytime you refresh the page?

**Edit --**
if you added the same item it should update the `{Quantity:}`

Following the answer below, I tried updating item quantity of the existing item however that didn't work. Any suggestion?

```
cartItems.forEach(function (item, i) {
            if (item.Product == key) {
                item.Quantity = drinkCounter[key].count;
                // item.Quantity += 1; // or no avail
                index = i;
            }
        });
```

Fixed localStorage quantity count

```
if (index !== -1) {
  cartItems[index].Quantity = parseInt(cartItems[index].Quantity) + 1 + 'x';
} else {
  var cartObj = { Product: key, Price: drinkCounter[key].price, Quantity: drinkCounter[key].count + 'x ' }
  cartItems.push(cartObj);
}
```

**Edit -- **
Quick question about total price, can someone point out why when I add an item the totalPrice is `0` when it should be the item price

Comment: `sessionStorage` will be removed once the page is reloaded! I think yu meant to use `localStorage`!

Comment: Sorry I changed it in my code, forgot to change it here. but yeah it should be `localStorage`. But the issue also exists using `localStorage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid stringifying localStorage data.

```
var data = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('cart') );
for (var key in drinkCounter) {
...       

    // search for a product with current key
    var index = -1;
    data.forEach(function(item, i){
        if( item.Product === key ) {
            index = i;
        }
    });

    if (index !== -1) {
        // data[index] = cartObj;
        data[index].Quantity = parseInt(data[index].Quantity.split(x)[0]) + drinkCounter[key].count + 'x ';
    } else {
        var cartObj = { Product: key, Price: drinkCounter[key].price, Quantity: drinkCounter[key].count + 'x ' };
        data.push(cartObj);
    }
...
}

localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: but how can you update the quantity of the same item you've added after page refresh?

Comment: tried adding `item.Quantity = drinkCounter[key].count;` in `if()` conditions, but that didn't work

Comment: `var data = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('cart') ) || [];` in case the `cart` is not set yet!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yeah I put the condition now too :), just need to update the quantity now.

Comment: Updated my question following the answer above, trying to update item quantity of existing item in the storage. Can someone shed a light why its not updating, when I add the same item the quantity reset back to 1 as it sees it as a new item.

Comment: It is not updating because you store not the number, but a string value, like `1x `. You will need to convert it to an integer - check my updated answer. But this is not the best way to do that.  Rather store a pure integer in the `Quantity` property and either add another property like `QuantityString` to keep the format you want - `1x `, or just add `x` when showing it.

Comment: tried the update was getting `[0]` error, mind editing the jsfiddle?

Comment: figured it out now, but its quantity in the storage isn't adding up correctly `cartItems[index].Quantity = parseInt(cartItems[index].Quantity.split(index)[0]) + drinkCounter[key].count + 'x ';` Using the update https://jsfiddle.net/svL8omhw/2/

Comment: I rewrote the whole thing here - https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/yg0nyr8j/.   It might also make sense to show saved cart on page load (this feature is not there).

Comment: the fiddle kinda different from what I intend to achieve, I basically just want to update the item quantity of the same item you add. The `localStorage` Items are already showing my original code on page load, I didn't include it in fiddle because its not part of the question.

Comment: I also tried ` parseInt(cartItems[index].Quantity.split(index)[0]) + 1 + 'x ' ` before your comment the count is still not right.

Comment: I think i fixed it now `cartItems[index].Quantity = parseInt(cartItems[index].Quantity) + 1 + 'x';`